# Adding user inout to JSON array in PHP using $_POST returns "null" array

Tags: php, arrays, json, input, associative

I'm trying to add user input to a JSON file of multidimensional array using $_POST and I've got it to write it into the JSON file, however it just displays:
{"title":null,"organiser":null,"date":null,"time":null,"type":null,"location":null,"contact":null} I have no idea where the issue is located, pls help :(

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Submit</title>
    </head>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="submit.css">
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="events.json"></script>

<body class="container">
<form method="POST" action="events.json" enctype="application/json">
  <h1>Submit an Event</h1>
 
    Event Title:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Event Title" required> 
    <br>
    Event Organiser(s):
    <br>
    <input type="text" size= "30" class="form-control" name="organiser" placeholder="Enter Name of Event Organiser(s)" required> 
    <br>

    Event Date:
    <br>     
    <input type="date" size= "30" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Enter Event Date" required> 
    <br>

    Event Time:
    <br>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="time" placeholder="Enter Event Time" required> 
    <br>

    Event Type:
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" name="type" required>
        <option>Sports Event</option>
        <option>Guest Lecture </option>
        <option>Conference</option>
        <option>SU Event</option>
        <option>Other</option>
        <br>
        <ul class="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="other" placeholder="If other please specify">
    </select>
    <br>

    Event Location:
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" name="location" required>
        <option>Keele SU</option>
        <option>K2</option>
        <option>Keele Hall</option>
        <option>Westminster Theatre</option>
        <option>David Weatherall Building</option>
        <option>Other</option>
        <br>
        <ul class="">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="other" placeholder="If other please specify">
        </ul>
    </select>
    <br>

    Contact Details:
    <br>
    <input type="text" size="30" class="form-control" name="contact" placeholder="Please Enter a Contact Email" required>
    <br>

 <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
 <button type="reset" class="btn-primary">Reset</button>
 </form>
 <script>
 <?php 
 
 $items = array(
 "title" => $_POST['title'], "organiser" => $_POST['organiser'], 
 "date" => $_POST['date'], "time" => $_POST['time'], "type" => $_POST["type"],
 "location" => $_POST['location'], "contact" => $_POST['contact']);

 $text = json_encode($items);
 $file = "events.json";
 $current = file_get_contents($file); //stores events.json as a string
 $decode = json_decode($current, true); //decodes events.json, associative array
 array_push($decode, $items);
 $data = json_encode($decode);
 file_put_contents("events.json", $data);

 ?>
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're posting the form to `events.json`, not the PHP script. And `enctype="application/json"` isn't supported by browsers AFAIK.

Comment: @Barmar so where should i be posting the form to if not to events.php?

Comment: It should be to `events.php` (if that's the name of the above script), but you're posting to `events.json`. Also, the script need to check whether it's running from the form submission or when just loading the form the first time. Check either `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` or give a name to the submit button and check of `$_POST['submit_button_name']` is set.

Comment: This is all basic PHP form processing, should be covered in most tutorials.

Comment: @Barmar i've changed it to the right php file and it's displaying in there but it still says null, thanks for your help so far though, v much appreciated

Comment: Are you checking whether the form was submitted before trying to use `$_POST` variables?

Comment: And get rid of `enctype`

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks like your form action is incorrect it should be this php filename, also you should check for $_POST to be set before trying to update your json file, what you are doing here is when you load the page it will update your json